# Powershell Get-PSDrive Issues

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell. I want to write a Powershell script to backup a folder on my smartphone to my Windows 10 PC. In Explorer I can see the Phone as a device but issuing the command **gdr** only lists the C: drive and other internal stuff but not the Phone as a device.

I just need a script to issue a ROBOCOPY command to mirror a folder on the phone to a folder on my PC.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your phone connected via bluetooth, USB, wireless, or some other means?  What is your phone manufacturer/model?  Was your PowerShell session started before or after the phone was connected?  Give this a try: Open Windows Explorer; navigate into a folder on your phone; then type `powershell` in Windows Explorer address bar (top) and press [Enter] (or, File menu > Open Windows PowerShell).

Comment: Connected via USB. In Windows Explorer, while on a folder on the phone, [File menu > Open Windows PowerShell] item is disabled. In a Powershell session opened AFTER the phone is connected, PS cmdlet Get-Volume does not list the phone. Phone manufacturer is Oppo. I was using Samsung before but there was no problem by using Samsung's own Smartswitch but Oppo does not have a similar utility.